# EOutOfResources when loading image (icon) in design-time

Tags: image, delphi, load, icons

I am trying to load an image into a control that has an image property, like TTrayIcon's Icon, TImage's Picture, in the Delphi IDE (design time), but it gives me an "Out of system resources" error when I have selected my image in the File dialog.

This is the Load Image dialog, so you know what I'm talking about.

[image: Image Dialog]

I got over 1 GB free memory, and I have rebooted several times, whereafter I only open Delphi, but its not helping..

Also, it's only happening for this one project.

Comment: you're giving no information that will help. What does "load an image" mean? Load into what? What kind of image?

Comment: @Ken Load an image into a control that has an image property, like TTrayIcon's Icon, TImage's Picture...

Comment: Please get in the habit of answering all questions about more info. For instance, I asked "Load into what??", which you answered. I also asked "What kind of image?", which you ignored. Lucky for you, Craig was able to guess what your problem was and help solve it.

Comment: @Ken - I misunderstood the "What kind of image". I thought you meant like a TPicture, or TBitmap, however thats just me being an idiot.

Comment: This may be a limitation of Delphi 7. I can load 64x64 and 128x128 icons (and lots of them) at either design-time or run-time. But load a single 256x256 icon and you get the "Out of resources" error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're not actually out of resources this generally happens either because the image file is too large to fit in memory once it's been decoded, or there's some corruption in the file that makes Delphi think it's larger than it should be.  Try opening it in an image program like [Paint.Net](http://www.getpaint.net/), make sure it's not too large, and resave it.

Comment: It's an Icon, (.ico), what can I do then? I used Icon Workshop to save it in RGBA 16x16.

Comment: Fixed by removing Vista compression - it never behaved like that before though.